# Extracting Grids containing 50% polygons (from land use layer) using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, overlay

I have a vector layer of Parcels for a certain area. I need to make grids of 100m * 100m over the parcel layer and then extract those grids which contain 50% or parcels by area.

I am currently using QGIS. The have tried taking an intersection of the Grids and the parcels and then run a selection query to select the ones where the area of the intersection (of parcel and grid) should be greater than 50m.

Is there any direct tool or plugin that serves the same purpose?